# Send mail in JS

Tags: javascript

How can I send the ip adress from this script to my mail? I need to put it in the field "Text". Please help.
I've tried to put there various think in the field "Text" but it doesn't work or the was a communicate "[object HTMLInputElement]"

```
<script>      
    document.getElementById('myIPs').value = "";
    window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection ||
                               window.mozRTCPeerConnection || 
                               window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]}), 
        noop = function(){};      
    pc.createDataChannel("");
    pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);

    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){
        if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate){ return};
        var myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];
        pc.onicecandidate = noop;
        document.getElementById('myIPs').value = document.getElementById('myIPs').value + myIP;
    }

    function sendMail(e){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('This will send the mail through SmtpJS');
        Email.send("piotr.hermanowicz@sth.com",
          "piotr.hermanowicz@sth.com",
          "Subject",
          "Text",
          "mail.mail.com",
          "piotr.hermanowicz@sth.com",
          "*****"
        );
    }

    window.onload = sendMail;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the best one. I used this on iOS to allow users to send links to articles. Every environment should have a mail client configured and `mailto` works for mobile.

Comment: But I want to send automatic email while somebody will open the website, he shouldn't know that sth was send to me. It is inside the corporate test.
I want to put the value of myIPs into the message to me.

Comment: @Hermanov for that use `window.onload = function() {
  window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body'); 
}`

Comment: Ok, but its open the window to send the mail, I want to send the mail automaticly to my mail.